# How to make the navigation bar(header) color to same as the body in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native, and was wondering if there was a way to have the navigation bar background color the same as the body's background color?

I'm aware of the following way to change background color by hardcoding a value, but is there a way to access the body's background color and then subsequently set the navigation header's background color to that?

```
defaultNavigationOptions: {
title: 'Home',
headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'white', // don't want to hardcode a value
}, ...
```

ie. in the `backgroundColor` setting, instead of 'white', how can I replace that to be the backgroundColor of the container/App in general? In the picture below, I'd like the white header to be the same color as the blue (without hardcoding the value of blue, since in my app, the color of the body changes based on the weather, etc.)

(And in other parts of my app, I dynamically change the background color by doing some thing like this:)

```
... backgroundColor: weather[this.state.weather].backgroundColor
```

Which unforunately doesn't work when I try that in `defaultNavigationOptions`

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but have you tried setting it to transparent?

Comment: Yup, tried setting it to transparent, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: First what kind of navigation are you using?

Comment: How though? Did you try setting it to an `rgba()` with zero opacity...(eg.`rgba(0,0,0,0)`)?

Comment: @JeffGuKang I'm using 'react-navigation' to do it, which is probably why the header navigation part exists in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman Yea I tried `transparent` as well as the rgba you just suggested, but neither works.

Comment: @JWong It will be better to show your code more specifically.

Comment: I found a workaround this by using the `headerMode: 'none'` option. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. What I did was to get rid of the top bar from react-navigation. Put this after constructor:

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
```

Then I added my own component for the top bar which color you can control easily. Just do it with a view, it's that simple! What is left is the status bar (the small space holding time, battery life etc.). You can mention it as component (remember to import it first), or simply call the set color method after import. The way I did it:

```
<StatusBar  backgroundColor="#7e7e7e" barStyle="light-content" />
```

But this is also possible:|

```
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#009ddc')
StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with this myself. I find configuring header bars with `react-navigation` very un-intuitive, resulting in unexpected behavior. any way, it seems like what you want is to display, a title in your header bar, while also have the header bar be the same color as your page, and not displaying the little semi-transparent line at the bottom of the header bar (at least in iOS anyways).

This is how I did it. Firstly, in my navigator's stack/drawer/etc config object, you need to set `headerMode: 'screen'` like:

```
const stackConfig = {
  initialRouteName: "Login",
  headerMode: "screen"
}
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(someRouteConfig, stackConfig)
```

( I had to do this because in my stack, I wanted a header bar on some screens but not others. this acts in a way that lets you customize from screen-to-screen)

From there, inside your screen component (or routeConfig object) you'll need :

```
static navigationOptions = {
  headerShown: true, (again this was for my screen-to-screen showing/hiding)
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: Colors.YOUR_COLOR_CONST}, (where Colors is a file with all your color constants, so not hardcoded)
  headerTransparent: true (this removes the whole header section, but allows you to still show title, header buttons etc. 
  you'll just have to adjust your content's upper margin to account for the "lack" of a 
  header bar...even though its still kind of there...but not...I know it's confusing)
}
```